# Read specific fields from webpage and save to string in C#

Tags: c#, field, html

I'm stuck at trying to retrieve some data from a webpage to a string from specific fields, so I can publish the data obtained in an application I am currently developing.

I have explored the use of WebClient, but I am not sure if I am barking at the right tree to accomplish this.

Could you please point me in the right direction?

UPDATE: This is what I have, but from this code, I only get the complete content of the page, instead of specific field:

```
namespace WebClientExperiments
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Window mainWindow = new Window();

       static WebClient readFromWeb = new WebClient();

        string sampleString = readFromWeb.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbInfoTxtBox.Text = sampleString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried and elaborate on the issues you're having with the code you've written.

Comment: You're looking for HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: You mean you want to scrap a web page and retrive some data or text from a html tag in special tag in that page?

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTMLAGILITYPACK to scrap data in a web page and retrive content of special tag which you want..!
Download it from [Here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) And Here i can show you an example :

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;


string Price;
HtmlWeb Sitehtml = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document = Sitehtml.Load(SITE_ADDRESS); // Site address can be like this : http://www.nerkhyab.com
HtmlNode node = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h2");//recognizing Target Node
Price = node.InnerHtml;//put text of target node in variable
```

Comment: Attention : The Site address must be exactly same as the address of web page that contains your goal tag
My goal tag here is text of "h2" tag

Answer (score -1):

You should try using `string.indexOf()` to find where the tag will be in the form, and then just use that index to read what comes next.  e.g.

```
var index = sampleString.indexOf('findstring'); 
if(index >= 0) { 
  sampleString = sampleString.Substring(index+9);
}
```